# using list of variables in apache conf file

Tags: apache, apache2.4, apache-config, apache-modules

Is there a way to pass list of variables and then process them one by on in conf file ?

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember  http://host1:4001
    BalancerMember  http://host2:5001 
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /someuri/  balancer://mycluster/someuri/
ProxyPassReverse /someuri/  balancer://mycluster/someuri/
</IfModule>
```

Above works fine to load balance, but number of instances to load balance can increase 2 to n. And i want to pass that list of hosts from outside using mod_macro or something.

Something like below

1> set vars

```
hosts="host1:4001","host2:5001"
```

2>use it

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>    
    for(host in $hosts)
    {
        BalancerMember  host
    }
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /someuri/  balancer://mycluster/someuri/
ProxyPassReverse /someuri/  balancer://mycluster/someuri/
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible, the closest thing that's available is mod_macro but that's for repeating large blocks, not expanding lists inside existing sections.

This kind of thing could be implemented a handful of ways, it just doesn't exist yet.